# Where is ApiTester.php for Codeception?

Tags: php, testing, codeception, acceptance-testing, web-api-testing

I followed these guides to start writing test for our APIs

- http://codeception.com/docs/10-WebServices
- http://mariobasic.com/api-testing-using-codeception-and-laravel/

Unfortunately, there is no file called ApiTester.php in folder tests/api, so running

```
  php codecept.phar run
```

gives me such error:

```
 [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]

fopen(/Users/jj/Development/codeception/tests/api/ApiTester.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

Somehow I have missed running

```
 php codecept.phar build
```

in both articles.